# Using context.read to access another bloc's data in a method (flutter_bloc)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

The [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts) of flutter_bloc says that:

> context.read is most commonly used for retrieving a bloc instance in order to add an event within onPressed callbacks.

Is it a good practice to use it to access Bloc A's data before adding an event for Bloc B? Or do better ways or patterns exist to accomplish this?

For eg.:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';


class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetA({super.key});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WidgetB(
          onPressed: () {
                final String varA =  context.read<BlocABloc>().state.maybeWhen(
                                          success: (data) => data.varA,
                                          orElse: () => "",
                                     );
                context.read<BlocBBloc>().add(BlocBEvent.eventXyz(varA: varA));
                return Future.value();
          },
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a bloc builder

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetA({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<BlocABloc, BlocAState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return WidgetB(
          onPressed: () {
            context.read<BlocBBloc>().add(
                  BlocBEvent.eventXyz(
                    varA: state.maybeWhen(
                      success: (data) => data.varA,
                      orElse: () => "",
                    ),
                  ),
                );
            return Future.value();
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```